# How to select data between dates where the checkin and checkout field type is in varchar?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select data between dates from a table

for eg:guestrocordtransac(tbl name)

```
id,roomno,roomtype, checkin,       checkout
 1  101      Baywatch  05/17/2015 05/24/2015
 2  102      BayWatch  05/10/2015 05/16/2015
```

when i tried writing query like this i get only one roomno as 101

```
SELECT roomno FROM guestrocordtransac where checkin between "05/14/2015" and "05/29/2015"
```

Answer (score 4):

The correct answer is to fix your data so the date values are stored as date/times.  It is almost always better to use native database types for values.

The second best thing (and it is a very remote second best) is to do the conversion on the fly:

```
SELECT roomno
FROM guestrocordtransac
where str_to_date(checkin, '%m/%d/%Y') between '2015-05-14' and '2015-05-29';
```

When using date constants, use the ISO standard format of YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: no its not working....My data stored not as date it is as varchar...

Comment: @ram this solution is because your data is stored as a varchar or string instead of a date.... Show the error message or result if it doesn't work

Comment: ram - say why it's not working: Wrong results? Error message? Hotel room caught fire?

Comment: if its a date format field then how can i insert my date as m/d/Y formate......since the date format is 0000:00:00

Comment: i need it for dispaly

Comment: @ram . . . Then use `date_format()` to format the value when you display it.